# Excel-VBA Comparing Column Data

Tags: excel, vba

I am completely new to Excel VBA, and I need to write code to do a simple task. I need to compare values in two different columns row by row, and see if the difference exceeds 50. If so, I need to highlight the entire row.

I program in other languages, so I have a basic understanding for how this works, but I have no clue how to navigate cells/view the content inside the cells. I tried this but it didn't work out (it would just highlight every single row). I simplified it to compare if values are equal or not, but to no avail (still everything is highlighted) Can anyone give me some help?

```
Dim strF0_col As Integer, sF0_col As Integer
Dim myRow, counter As Integer
Dim rEnd As Integer

Sub compare_F0()
    rEnd = 100
    strF0_col = 307
    sF0_col = 317
    counter = 0

    For myRow = 2 To rEnd Step 1
        Application.StatusBar = counter & "rows highlighted."
        If (Cells(myRow, strF0_col).Value = Cells(myRow, sF0_col).Value) Then
            Cells(myRow, strF0_col).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 28
        End If
    Next myRow
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ah I used the wrong columns to compare data, so that's what went wrong with the above code. Now I can't seem to figure out how to find the difference in the If-statement.

Comment: I tried something like: If ((Cells(myRow, "KU").Value - Cells(myRow, "LE").Value) > Abs(50)) Then... But this doesn't work like it would in C++

Comment: Sorry, I figured everything out. I put the Abs() on the wrong side. Doing everything in a hurry right now!

Comment: You don't need VBA to do this.  Conditional Formatting will handle all of this more easily (except for the status bar message).

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason to do not use Conditional Formatting, as @Doug Glancy suggested?

It worked quite fine here for me.

In case you want to give it a shoot, do as follows...

- Choose the whole row
- Open Conditional Formatting Menu (will depend on your Excel version. Anyway...)
- Add the Rule `=$KU2>$LE2+50`
- Set the format you want (maybe fill in yellow?)
- Confirm
- Copy format to other rows

Notice the row index (2, in this case) cannot have the $ symbol.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to highlight rows that are blank?

If so, use

```
If Cells(myRow, strF0_col).Value <> "" And _
   Cells(myRow, strF0_col).Value = Cells(myRow, sF0_col).Value Then
```

As an aside, accessing cell values like this is quite slow.  If you are only processing 100 rows then its fast enough, but if this number grows then you will find it slows down to a painful degree.

It is much faster to copy the range values to a variant array an then loop over that.  Search SO for `[Excel] "Variant Array"`  There are many answers that show how to do this and explain why it helps